# In OSB when there are WSDL updates in the web service

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, wsdl, osb

In OSB when the webservice WSDL gets updated and the proxy service and business service has the old WSDL, does OSB generate an error if the WSDLs do not match?

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the nature of changes that occurs in WSDL.
There are some changes that are tolerable such as adding a method. Other are not, such as removing a compulsory input parameter .

I advice you to use 'membrane' , it's nice tools that can help you to see if there is any bad regression in your WSDL document
http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model/

Comment: Is this part of the Java API, if not is it open source.

Comment: Yes it's open, you can install it http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model-doc/1.4/cmd-tool/installation.htm

Comment: +1, it's all about what will cause serialization to fail. If your service def removes some nillable properties on an object and you don't update the client, then as long as you don't call the service with those properties set, it will work. If you add those old props back, you'll get an error. Rules of thumb: If you're adding something on the service that the client needs to call, or changing the structure of an existing call, you need to update. If after the service is changed it supports the same structure of existing requests, and hasn't added any new required props, you're probably good.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh workspace and Reopen ProxyService.

Comment: Thanks for the reply what I am trying to say is does osb generate an error message, whether in Eclipse or in the sbconsole.